# How to use patterns in a case statement?

Tags: bash, pattern-matching, case

The `man` page says that `case` statements use "filename expansion pattern matching".
I usually want to have short names for some parameters, so I go:

```
case $1 in
    req|reqs|requirements) TASK="Functional Requirements";;
    met|meet|meetings) TASK="Meetings with the client";;
esac

logTimeSpentIn "$TASK"
```

I tried patterns like `req*` or `me{e,}t` which I understand would expand correctly to match those values in the context of filename expansion, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 211):

Brace expansion doesn't work, but `*`, `?` and `[]` do. If you set `shopt -s extglob` then you can also use [extended pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching):

- `?()` - zero or one occurrences of pattern
- `*()` - zero or more occurrences of pattern
- `+()` - one or more occurrences of pattern
- `@()` - one occurrence of pattern
- `!()` - anything except the pattern

Here's an example:

```
shopt -s extglob
for arg in apple be cd meet o mississippi
do
    # call functions based on arguments
    case "$arg" in
        a*             ) foo;;    # matches anything starting with "a"
        b?             ) bar;;    # matches any two-character string starting with "b"
        c[de]          ) baz;;    # matches "cd" or "ce"
        me?(e)t        ) qux;;    # matches "met" or "meet"
        @(a|e|i|o|u)   ) fuzz;;   # matches one vowel
        m+(iss)?(ippi) ) fizz;;   # matches "miss" or "mississippi" or others
        *              ) bazinga;; # catchall, matches anything not matched above
    esac
done
```

Comment: This answer helped me because I had enclosed my pattern in double quotes ("a*") and that wasn't working

Comment: Some versions of bash won't support `@(...)` even with `shopt -s extglob` enabled

Comment: @YzmirRamirez: I'd be curious to know which versions. `extglob` has been in Bash since bash-2.02-alpha1 (about 1998).

Comment: @phyatt that link helped me solve a more complicated `case` problem.

Answer (score 49):

I don't think you can use braces.

According to the Bash manual about case in [Conditional Constructs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html).

> Each *pattern* undergoes tilde
>   expansion, parameter expansion,
>   command substitution, and arithmetic
>   expansion.

Nothing about [Brace Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) unfortunately.

So you'd have to do something like this:

```
case $1 in
    req*)
        ...
        ;;
    met*|meet*)
        ...
        ;;
    *)
        # You should have a default one too.
esac
```

Answer (score 10):

**`if` and `grep -Eq`**

```
arg='abc'
if printf '%s' "$arg" | grep -Eq 'a.c|d.*'; then
  echo 'first'
elif printf '%s' "$arg" | grep -Eq 'a{2,3}'; then
  echo 'second'
fi
```

where:

- `-q` prevents `grep` from producing output, it just produces the exit status
- `-E` enables extended regular expressions

I like this because:

- it is POSIX 7
- it [supports extended regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04), unlike POSIX `case`
- the syntax is less clunky than case statements when there are few cases

One downside is that this is likely slower than `case` since it calls an external `grep` program, but I tend to consider performance last when using Bash.

**`case` is POSIX 7**

Bash appears to follow POSIX by default without `shopt` as mentioned by https://stackoverflow.com/a/4555979/895245

Here is the quote: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_01 section "Case Conditional Construct":

> The conditional construct case shall execute the compound-list corresponding to the first one of several patterns (see Pattern Matching Notation) [...] Multiple patterns with the same compound-list shall be delimited by the '|' symbol. [...]
>
> The format for the case construct is as follows:
>
> ```
> case word in
>    [(] pattern1 ) compound-list ;;
>    [[(] pattern[ | pattern] ... ) compound-list ;;] ...
>    [[(] pattern[ | pattern] ... ) compound-list]
> esac
> ```

and then http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13 section "2.13. Pattern Matching Notation" only mentions `?`, `*` and `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this Q&A a few times now, here is my slightly different point of view now.

> I usually want to have short names for some parameters

Of course I prefer shorter code too. However...

```bash
case $1 in
    "req"|"reqs"|"requirements"|"many more"|"strings"| \
    "and"|"patterns"|"here")
        TASK="Functional Requirements";;
    "met"|"meet"|"meetings")
        TASK="Meetings with the client";;
esac
```

... works, and I don't get any complaints from shellcheck. You could even put every pattern on a separate line and sort them alphabetically if that pleases you.