# can i use regex in a bash shell script

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I am a first year Computer technician student, and before now have never actually used linux.  I grasped the basics of scripting fairly quickly and am trying to write a script that will create a directory and a soft link for each assignment. seeing as we average two assignments a week i thought this would be helpful.

I am having trouble making my script accept only numbers as variables. I have it mostly working (mostly) with use of 3 case statements, but would rather use basic regex with an if statement, if I can.

```
if [ $# != 1 ]; then

    red='\033[0;31m'
    NC='\033[0m'
    blue='\033[1;34m'
    NC='\033[0m'
    echo 1>&2 "${blue}ERROR:${NC} $0 :${red}expecting only one variable, you gave $#($*)${NC}"
    echo 1>&2 "${blue}Usage:${NC} $0 :${red}number of assignment.${NC}"
    exit 2

fi


case $1 in

    [[:punct:]]*) echo 1>&2 "Numeric Values Only"
    exit 2
    ;;
    [[:alpha:]]*) echo 1>&2 "Numeric Values Only"
    exit 2
    ;;
    [[:space:]]*) echo 1>&2 "Numeric Values Only"
    exit 2
    ;;
esac
```

the script then makes the directory and creates a soft link for the marking script (if its posted), and ends. can anyone help me shorten/eliminate the case statements

Comment: possible duplicate of [patterns in case statement in bash scripting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554718/patterns-in-case-statement-in-bash-scripting)

Comment: Or see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806906/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-is-a-number-in-bash

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use regular expressions in portable shell scripts (ones that will run on any POSIX compliant shell). In general, patterns in the shell are [globs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching), not regular expressions.

That said, there are a few other options. If you are using Bash specifically, you have two choices; you can use extended globs, which give you some regex like functionality:

```
shopt -s extglob

case $1 in
    +([[:digit:]]) ) echo "digits" ;;
    *) echo "not digits" ;;
esac
```

Another option is that Bash has the `=~` operator in the [`[[ ]]` conditional construct](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) to match strings against a regex; this doesn't work in a `case` statement, but works in an `if`:

```
if [[ $1 =~ [0-9]+ ]]
then
    echo "digits"
fi
```

Finally, if you want to do regular expression matching portably (so it will run in other POSIX shells like `ash`, `dash`, `ksh`, `zsh`, etc), you can call out to `grep`; if you pass `-q`, it will be silent about the matches but return success or failure depending on whether the input matched:

```
if echo "$1" | grep -qE "[0-9]+"
then
    echo "digits"
fi
```

Comment: all options produced more error messages, but with the use of a few more case statements the script is only accepting numeric values now.

Comment: @DanielPeregrym If you show the exact code that you used, and the exact error messages that you got (edit your question with the updated information), I can probably help you fix those errors. I tested every one of those examples before posting them, so I know that they work; I'd be interested to see why they aren't working for you.