# bash case statement syntax error using extended pattern matching

Tags: bash, switch-statement, pattern-matching, syntax-error

This code running on GNU bash, version 5.0.7(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu):

```
var="r=x"
case "$var" in
        r=?(x|xy|xyz))
                echo "suchess"
                ;;
esac
```

Is generating this error:

```
bash: test.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: test.sh: line 3: `        r=?(x|xy|xyz))'
```

Cannot for the life of me figure out why...  tested code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554718/how-to-use-patterns-in-a-case-statement) and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Argh.  So this is embarrassing.  I found the answer almost as soon as I posted this.  The answer is in the link in my question.  I needed to add:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

To the start of script.

Hope this helps someone else in the future.

Answer found here:  [How to use patterns in a case statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554718/how-to-use-patterns-in-a-case-statement)

Answer (score 2):

Also, optionally, you don't have use/set the `extglob` option explicitly and do this match with a `case` statement. If you are using `bash`, the `test` operator provides this match when using with `==`

```
var="r=x"
if [[ $var == r=?(x|xy|xyz) ]]; then
    printf '%s\n' "success"
fi
```

Ensure you do not quote the glob pattern in the right side of the `==` operator. Either use it above or do a variable assignment to store the glob and do an unquoted comparison

```
glob="r=?(x|xy|xyz)"
if [[ $var == $glob ]]; then
```